# how to handled null exception in Db.SingleDecimal?

Tags: c#, dbnull, argumentnullexception

```
c = new TableCell();
decimal pembayaran = Db.SingleDecimal("Select (valuta) from ArInvoice where customerID='01');
c.Text = Cf.Num(pembayaran);
c.Attributes["style"] = "text-align: right;";
tr.Cells.Add(c);
```

it works when the query have a value, but it contains this error when the result is null
"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"

How I solve this problem?

Comment: What tool/library is that with a `SingleDecimal` method? Is that your own? or...? 'cos the change would need to be made in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following method call:

```
Db.SingleDecimal("Select (valuta) from ArInvoice where customerID='01');
```

Not sure what it does exactly since the method definition is not provided in the question, but I am guessing it tries to convert a `DBNull` value to another type. You need to show the exact definition of that method for better help, but you'd generally handle the `DBNull` with something like this:

```
var myDecimal = dr.IsDBNull(0) ? 0M : dr.GetDecimal(0); // get a decimal from the first column
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not directly familiar with any tool with a `SingleDecimal` method, so I'll answer in the general sense:

When querying data from ADO.NET (directly or indirectly), it is pretty likely that (possibly both) you will get some kind of "reader" API (most likely `IDataReader`), or that you will get raw `object` values.

In the first case, you should have access to an `IsDBNull` method (per column); so call that method, and do whatever you want to do with nulls.

In the second case, you should check the value for `DBNull`, i.e. `if(val is DBNull`).

In both cases, what the code does next is up to the library. In both cases, you might need to think about ***two*** null-esque scenarios here: no rows, and a row with a single value.

Frankly, in both cases it would be easier to use a library/tool that has existing support for this. For example, with dapper, this would just be:

```
string customerId = "01";
decimal? pembayaran = Db.Query<decimal?>(
    "Select valuta from ArInvoice where customerID=@customerId",
    new { customerId }).Single();
```

which gives you:

- correct parameterisation
- null handling
- the same API for querying all data (`Query<T>`)
- the ability to use any LINQ you like for ordinality (`Single()`, `First()`, `ToList()`, etc)

If you wanted to use a default value (rather than an empty `decimal?` when the cell's value was `null`, you could just use:

```
decimal pembayaran = Db.Query<decimal?>(
    "Select valuta from ArInvoice where customerID=@customerId",
    new { customerId }).Single() ?? 0M;
```

here note the `?? 0M` is just a null-coalescing operation to get a zero `decimal` in place of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer from my own question, hehe. I use **select isnull((valuta),0)** in sql, so it will replace with 0 when the result is DbNull.

```
decimal pembayaran = Db.SingleDecimal("Select isnull((valuta),0) from ArInvoice where customerID='01');
```

But if you want to take some action when the result is DbNull (not only set the default value) maybe u can try the Eren Ersönmez's or Marc Gravell's answer. 
Happy Coding :D